# why incrementing a float has different results than expected ??

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying some basic c questions when a query struck me. I tried the following code to resolve it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef  float mytype;
mytype q=1;
mytype *x=&q;
mytype *y=&q;
mytype *z=&q;
mytype *a=&q;
mytype *b=&q;
mytype *arr[5]={x,y,z,a,b};
int main()
{ 

        printf("********************");
        //printf("%u\n",sizeof(int*));
        printf("%u\n",sizeof(double*));
        printf("********************\n");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%p\n",arr[i]);
        printf("%p\n",arr[i]+1);
        printf("***********");
    }
}
```

when i execute it,sizeof float pointer is 8bytes but incrementing it results in an address that is only 4 bytes away.Can anyone please explain why that is so ??

Comment: "when i execute it,sizeof float pointer" - You don't get the size of a `float` pointer! And why should the size of the pointer be related to the size of the object it points to? There are a lot of wrong asumptions it that little code.

Comment: And the right format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu` not `%u`.

Answer (score 2):

The size of your pointer is 8 bytes on a 64 bit system.The size of what the pointer is referencing to is 4 bytes.

Eg, on 64 bit systems `float foo`:

`sizeof(&foo)` is 64 bits

`sizeof(foo)` is 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

You are running on a 64-bit system. The size of a pointer to a memory address is 8 bytes, but the size of a float is only 4 bytes (as a float is a single precision floating point number).

On a 64-bit system, all pointers are 8 bytes in length to allow memory addresses > 4GB to be addressed.

When you increment the pointer, you increment it by the size of a single float, which is 4 bytes in length, so the pointer is incremented by 4 bytes.

Comment: "When you increment the pointer, you add enough space for 1 more float" - **definitively not!** Incrementing a pointer does not _add_ any space.

Comment: @Olaf You're right, my phrasing was confusing there, I've changed it